# What can we do about java.util.Calendar constructor synchronizing on a static Hashtable?

Tags: java, concurrency, calendar

I was horrified to see many of our app threads competing to synchronize on a java.util.Hashtable.get(xx) method that gets accessed from the Calendar's constructor.

```
at java.util.Hashtable.get(java.lang.Object)
at java.util.Calendar.setWeekCountData(java.util.Locale)
at java.util.Calendar.<init>(java.util.TimeZone, java.util.Locale)
at java.util.GregorianCalendar.<init>(java.util.TimeZone, java.util.Locale)
```

The ctor looks up a static hashtable that is meant to be serve as a cache, but ends up blocking all threads.

```
/**
 * Cache to hold the firstDayOfWeek and minimalDaysInFirstWeek
 * of a Locale.
 */
private static Hashtable<Locale, int[]> cachedLocaleData = new Hashtable<Locale, int[]>(3);

protected Calendar(TimeZone zone, Locale aLocale)
{
    .. .. snip .. 
    setWeekCountData(aLocale);
}

private void setWeekCountData(Locale desiredLocale)
{
/* try to get the Locale data from the cache */
int[] data = cachedLocaleData.get(desiredLocale);

....
}
```

Is there a better way to manipulate dates? Does [Joda](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) bypass all these issues?

Comment: The best answer, in this case, is to use [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) instead of java.util.Calendar. Joda-Time is an open source calendar replacement that fixes an enormous amount of problems in Date/Calendar. Sadly, that does mean rewriting all the code that deals with threads, or at least, in the hot spots where you suffer from contention.

Comment: It appears that there is also a bug posting on the Sun forums - https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=834143

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to reuse the Calendar instances instead of constructing new ones.

Answer (score 4):

Better solution, use Java 7, the `Hashtable` has been replaced by a `ConcurrentMap`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the easiest solution (other than upgrading the underlying implementation) is to use a prototype instance and `clone` it.